# How to plot dataframe in which columns have intervals and numbers?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a sample of my data in TSV format:

```
w    x      y            z
A    204    250.60097    43.49554
B    225    135.21218    51.11727
C    304    [432,471]    70.80413
D    318    [463,479]    73.20682
```

It consists of 4 columns, where column `y` admits both intervals and numbers. I need to plot columns `x`, `y`, and `z` in separate horizontal facets. Each facet should have their values in the y-axis, and values in column `w` should be in the x-axis. The catch is that the intervals should be shown as bars in the plot, and the facet for column `y` should have the bars alongside the dots (for numbers).

Since I don't use R often, I'm having a lot of trouble with this. Could you help me?

**Edit 1:** I ran `dput(head(df))` as requested. I also updated the columns' names to conform with the output.

```r
structure(list(w = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
    x = c(204L, 225L, 304L, 318L), y = c("250.600972895687", 
    "135.212187604404", "[432,471]", "[463,479]"), z = c(43.4955443375464, 
    51.1172712956558, 70.8041394323353, 73.2068258760318)), row.names = 4:7, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: 1) Is column 3 the only column with intervals? 2) Can you edit the question with the output of `dput(head(df))`?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Done; I also added names for the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to plot the y column with Range - I didn't do the facet. Comment to let me know if this is solution you were looking for and if you need help to implement further with the facet.

### Solution using geom_errorbar

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gridExtra)
options(scipen = 999)

df <- structure(list(w = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                     x = c(204L, 225L, 304L, 318L), 
                     y = c("250.600972895687", "135.212187604404", "[432,471]", "[463,479]"), 
                     z = c(43.4955443375464, 51.1172712956558, 70.8041394323353, 73.2068258760318)), 
                row.names = 4:7, class = "data.frame")

# a generic function take the df & variable and produce a geom_errorbar graph
draw_plot <- function(df, var_name) {
  # Convert the range values in column "y" to separate minimum and maximum columns
  # if variables have range convert the range into min/max values
  df$var_min <- as.numeric(gsub("\\[(\\d+),.+", "\\1", df[[var_name]]))
  df$var_max <- as.numeric(gsub("\\[.+,(\\d+)]", "\\1", df[[var_name]]))
  
  # Create a bar plot with error bars using min/max values.
  ggplot(df, aes(x = w, y = (var_min + var_max) / 2)) +
    geom_point(stat = "identity", size = 5) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = var_min, ymax = var_max), width = 0.2) +
    labs(title = paste0("Plot of Column '", var_name, "' (with Range)"),
         x = "Category",
         y = "Value")
}

# list of variables to draw the plots
var_to_plot <- c("x", "y", "z")

# draw plot of each variable using purrr::map call
# with var_to_plot as input var_name
plot_list <- purrr::map(var_to_plot, draw_plot, df = df)

# using grid.arrange ncol=3 to draw them next to each other.
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_list, ncol= 3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Using error bars is better! Thank you! I'm trying to add the facet layer, but I'm having more trouble than I expected..

Comment: @LucasPeres - Not exactly using facet but with gridExtra it produce similar result while you have more control on each graph generation. Hope this provide you some foundation for further explore of R ;)